# Smoothness of a deformation functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, deformation-theory

In [his notes of deformation of complex structures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507286.pdf)  Manetti defined deformation as a functor of Artin rings. He also defines the smoothness of this functor as

Definition V.36. Let $F, G: \mathbf{A r t}_{\mathbb{K}} \rightarrow$ Set be two functors of Artin rings and $\eta: F \rightarrow G$ a natural transformation; $\eta$ is called smooth if for every small extension
$$
0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow B \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow 0
$$
the map
$$
(\eta, p): F(B) \rightarrow G(B) \times_{G(A)} F(A)
$$
is surjective.
A functor of Artin rings $F$ is called smooth if the morphism $F \rightarrow 0$ is smooth.

( A small extension $e$ in $\mathbf{A r t}_{\mathbb{K}}$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
e: \quad 0 \longrightarrow M \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow 0
$$
such that $B \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} A$ is a morphism in $\operatorname{Art}_{\mathbb{K}}$ and ker $p=i(M)$ is annihilated by the maximal ideal of $B$ (that is, as a $B$-module it is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space).)

This definition seems quite algebraic, what I know about the smoothness of a deformation of a complex manifold is that, a first order deformation, which lives in $H^1(M,T^{1,0})$, which is the first cech cohomology group with value in holomorphic vector bundle on the manifold, is smooth, if it can be integrated, that is, it is the first order term of a deformation of the complex manifold (deformation of a complex structure can be seen as deformation of integrable almost complex structure, which is a (1,1) tensor field). But how is this related to small extension of an exact sequence of abelian groups?

Comment: Here's an algebraic explanation for the terminology: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ